# Unable to create the multiple params in angular routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I was able to pass & create single parameter in the URL. When I tried to pass the second params from one component to another component. I'm facing an error saying "Cannot match any routes".
I tried to pass by using [queryParams] directive.

In app.routing.module.ts :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'' , component:MovieticketinfoComponent},
  {path:'ticketinfo', component:MovieticketinfoComponent},
  {path:'ticketpayment/:id1,:id2',component:TicketpaymentComponent}
];
```

My Component :

```
<label for="txtmoviename">Movie Name : </label>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="movie_name" id="txtmoviename"> <br/><br/>

<label for="txttktcount">No.of Tickets : </label>
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="ticket_count" name="ticketcount" id="txttktcount">

<br/>
<button id="btnsubmit" [routerLink]="['/ticketpayment']" [queryParams]="{id1:'movie_name',id2:'ticket_count' }">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not need to have comma in route for the second param. Just replace with `/`:

```
{path:'ticketpayment/:id1/:id2',component:TicketpaymentComponent}
```

And `routerLink` should look like this:

```
[routerLink]="['ticketpayment', 'movie_name','ticket_count']
```

Comment: Tried this, But still facing the same error.

Comment: {path:'ticketpayment/:id1/:id2',component:TicketpaymentComponent} and changed query params as : [queryParams]="{id1:'movie_name',id2:'ticket_count' }"

Comment: @SrikanthReddy please, see my updated answer